# Unable to connect to SQL server 2008 R2 via Instance name?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, connectivity, windows-8

I don't understand :

I've installed sql server 2008 R2. the installation process asked me for the desired instance name  , so I wrote: `MSSQLSERVER`.

after the installation , running *Setup Discovery Report* does shows me the instance name :

[image]

I've also installed all the service packs.

Also , all the services are up :

[image]

Also , all the ports are open ( tcp:1433 + udp :1434)

[image]

[image]

Also , Named pipes are on : [image]

So ,  where is the problem ?

I'm unable  to connect via the instance name :
[image]

Also unable   with :

`user\MSSQLSERVER` where `user` is the computer name.

Also unable  with : `.\MSSQLSERVER`

**But** (weird) :

Those 3 **do** work :

- `user` ( "user" is my machine name)
- `(local)`
- `.`

Question :

why I can't use my instance name to connect to my sql server ?

Related info :

After connecting via one of the 3 who work  , I run a helpful info :

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You selected the default instance name as the name of your instance.

[Instance Configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143531%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

"If you specify MSSQLServer for the instance name, a default instance will be created. For SQL Server Express, if you specify SQLExpress for the instance name, a default instance will be created."

To connect to the default instance you don't specify the instance name, only the server name.

Comment: Thanks. and what If I choose "lala" as instance name ?  would then I be able to cennect via ".\lala" ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir yes, if you connect from the computer where SQL Server is installed. Otherwise you need to specify the computer name instead of `.`. Something like `servername\instancename`.

Comment: @RoyiNamir you are welcome.

Answer (score -1):

Use below query to find exact instace name

```
DECLARE @GetInstances TABLE
( Value nvarchar(100),
 InstanceNames nvarchar(100),
 Data nvarchar(100))

Insert into @GetInstances
EXECUTE xp_regread
  @rootkey = 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE',
  @key = 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server',
  @value_name = 'InstalledInstances'

Select InstanceNames from @GetInstances
```

Comment: This barely answers the question.